# Span inside anchor or anchor inside span or doesn't matter?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I want to nest `span` and `a` tags. Should I

1. Put `<span>` inside `<a>`
2. Put `<a>` inside `<span>`
3. It doesn't matter ?

Answer (score 124):

3 - It doesn't matter.

BUT, I tend to only use a `<span>` inside an `<a>` if it's only for a *part* of the contents of the tag i.e.

```
<a href="#">some <span class="red">text</span></a>
```

Rather than:

```
<a href="#"><span class="red">some text</span></a>
```

Which should obviously just be:

```
<a href="#" class="red">some text</a>
```

Comment: I recently came across a white-space issue with text-overflow:ellipsis and overflow:hidden, which could be solved by adding an inline-block element to my a nav button. I ended up with <a><span>Text</span></a>. So I think (or hope ;)) it's okay to do this when you really need to.

Comment: I will go for option 2 because it does matter. Anchor should be just for anchoring and not for containing elements (best practice). Imagine a situation, where you  make a clickable tile and anchor is the parent element of the tile component and inside the component are the links for images, and more images. Google crawler will go crazy and will eventually, that's not good for you site.

Comment: @ImamBux - I would do the opposite, go for option 1 because the Anchor is (generally) not part of what the span represents, but the thing being represented is part of the anchor. Imagine an address that links to a map; the `<address>` is part of (or the whole) link, but the link `<a>` is not part of the address. With option 2, `<a><img...></a>` is common enough that you may end up frequently violating your rule.

Answer (score 37):

It is perfectly valid (at least by HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 standards) to nest either a `<span>` inside an `<a>` or an `<a>` inside a `<span>`.

Just to prove it to yourself, you can always check it out an the [W3C MarkUp Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org)

I tried validating:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>
         <a href="http://www.google.com/"><span>Google</span></a>
       </p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

And also the same as above, but with the `<a>` inside the `<span>`

i.e.

```
<span><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></span>
```

with both HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 doctypes, and both passed validation successfully!

Only thing to be aware of is to ensure that you close the tags in the correct order.  So if you start with a `<span>` then an `<a>`, make sure you close the `<a>` tag first before closing the `<span>` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 20):

It doesn't matter - they're both allowed inside each other.

Answer (score 18):

that depends on what you want to markup.

- if you want a link inside a span, put `<a>` inside `<span>`.
- if you want to markup something in a link, put `<span>` into `<a>`

Answer (score 17):

SPAN is a **GENERIC** inline container. It does not matter whether an `a` is inside `span` or `span` is inside `a` as both are inline elements. Feel free to do whatever seems logically correct to you.

Answer (score 3):

It can matter if for instance you are using some sort icon font. I had this just now with:

```
<span class="fa fa-print fa-3x"><a href="some_link"></a></span>
```

Normally I would put the span inside the A but the styling wasn't taking effect until swapped it round.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the span is for. If it refers to the text of the link, and not the fact that it is a link, choose #1. If the span refers to the link as a whole, then choose #2. Unless you explain what the span represents, there's not much more of an answer than that. They're both inline elements, can be syntactically nested in any order.

Comment: Correct, they are both inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, as a web developer, I only ever put a span within an anchor tag if I am trying to highlight a section of the links text, such as applying a background to one section.

Answer (score 0):

It will work both, but personally I'd prefer option 2 so the span is "around" the link.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically I think  makes more sense as  is a container for a single element and if you need to nest them then that suggests more than element will be inside of the outer one.