# Is it right to add <span> tag inside <a> tag?

Tags: html

I was wondering if we could add a span tag inside a tag....

```
<h2 style="text-align: left;"><a href="mydomain.com"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Dog dresses</span></a><br></h2>
```

**Is the above method right? Is it safe to use...???**

I know that We can define some class here and let it go inside other elements like this.

```
<h2><a href="mydomain" class="bold">Dog dresses</a></h2>

.bold {font-weight: bold; }
```

OR

```
<h2 class="bold"><a href="mydomain">Dog dresses</a></h2>

h2.bold a { font-weight: bold; }
```

Please share your views..

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it's fine. `<span>` is an inline element. Unless you add the css `display: block;` to it, it can go in the `<a>`.

Comment: NB that this changes in HTML 5 – [see this blog post](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/)

Comment: @lonesomeday What does NB mean?

Comment: It means "note that".

Comment: Note that what changes in HTML 5 is that you can use block elements in anchors, **not** that you can't use inline elements anymore…

Answer (score 14):

Both forms are legal. (`<a>` inside `<span>` or `<span>` inside `<a/>`)

```
<a><div></div></a> 
<!-- illegal < HTML 5, you cannot put block level tags in an <a> -->
<!-- legal in HTML 5 -->
```

BUT, normally I would only use a `<span>` inside an `<a>` for some purpose, because there is some content which needs special treatment

```
<a href="#">this is <span class="lookatme">special and needs treatment</span></a>
```

This is pointless (for me :-) )

```
<a href="#"><span class="lookatme">some text</span></a>
```

THis would normally be

```
<a href="#" class="lookatme">some text</a>
```

I normally think with `<heading>` tags, the `<a>` should be inside the `<heading>`, but I don't think it is wrong to do the reverse

Comment: "illegal: you cannot put block level tags in an <a>" - [Not in HTML 5, it isn't](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/)

Comment: I still live in an old XHTML world :-), but i have updated and learnt something new

Comment: The `<a>` is stylized as rectangle while the `<div>` inside is stylized separately - thus (your 2nd example) a required case for me.

Answer (score 3):

While that code *is* valid, it's not the best way to do it.

Here's your code again, indented for clarity

```
<h2 style="text-align: left;">
    <a href="mydomain.com">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Dog dresses</span>
    </a>
    <br>
</h2>
```

The first thing to notice is you have a trailing `<br>`. What's that for? Extra spacing? Well use `padding` instead!

Secondly, you don't need the span element - the bold style can be applied directly to the `<a>` tag.

Why not just write it like this:

```
<h2 style="text-align: left; padding-bottom: 1em">
    <a href="http://mydomain.com" style="font-weight: bold">Dog dresses</a>
</h2>
```

Comment: In this case there is no need, however I tend to add span tags within my anchor tags so that you can added "image buttons" to the link and hide the text that is within.

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure whether it's still acceptable, but you can keep the image and remove the text with `text-indent: -9999px`, which requires no extra element.

Comment: absolutely nothing wrong with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763235/span-inside-a-or-a-inside-span-or-doenst-matter `text-indent` to me is just a cheats way :P

Comment: @Tim: I was referring to my method being possibly unacceptable, not yours. I was just pointing out a way of doing it without extra markup.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly legal to have a `span` tag inside an `a` tag.

Also read this:

[Span inside anchor or anchor inside span or doesn't matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763235/span-inside-a-or-a-inside-span-or-doenst-matter)

Answer (score 1):

It is legal and safe. You can always check your markup at free validation service of w3 organisation: http://validator.w3.org/check

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves correctly, yes, you're allowed to have a `<span>` within an `<a>`, and an `<a>` within an `<h2>`. Where you define your class is up to you; put it wherever it makes most sense.

You can check if you've written valid HTML [here](http://validator.w3.org/), but don't fret too much if it doesn't validate as long as it renders correctly in all the prominent browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would perfer to use CSS rather then using  inside .
It reduce the complexity of HTML code, it reduce the stress to the browser, by not rendering complex structure.
Easy to grab using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a different perspective which lacks among answers. Imagine you want to achive something like this, partially linked header:

```
<h1><a href="stackoverflow.com">This</a> site is amazing</h1>
```

and a link which is a partial header:

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com"><h1>This</h1> site is amazing</a>
```

which makes not much sense but syntactically true.