# Can I use more then one span in a link?

Tags: html, css

Can I use more then one span in a link?

Like this:

```
<a href="#" class="sprite">
  <span class="iconSpan"></span>
  <span class="textSpan">text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<span>` is inline element so you can have any no of required span elements inside another html element.

Answer (score 1):

SPAN is a GENERIC inline container. It does not matter whether an a is inside span or `span` is inside `a` as both are inline elements. Feel free to do whatever seems logically correct to you.

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/nVNqU/

```
<a href="#" class="sprite iconSpan textSpan">
  text
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have as many as you need :) `a` attribute is like a `div`, it covers everything inside it :)

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are legal. (`<a>` inside `<span>` or `<span>` inside `<a/>`):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7427244/2523764

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have as many `span` as you will need.