# Should I nest an <i> inside an <a> or an <a> inside an <i>?

Tags: html, syntax

I am using an anchor tag, and the text that is displayed in the hyperlink is supposed to be italicized. When using the anchor, do I use the italics tags on the text itself or do I italicize the entire anchor tag? Which is the correct syntax?

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"><i>Google</i></a>
```

Or:

```
<i><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></i>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it right to add <span> tag inside <a> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427177/is-it-right-to-add-span-tag-inside-a-tag)

Comment: I didn't look into that one because I didn't think it was what I was looking for.  Will read.  Thanks, @bejado.

Comment: @bejado not a duplicate – that question was in 2011. HTML5 has changed things quite a bit.

Comment: @bejado HTML5 changed drastically. In HTML5, block and inline elements are gone and are replaced with broader categories, called content models which regulate what kind of elements can contain what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are completely valid. See the [HTML5 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) where the semantics and usages of the tags are explained. On the [`a` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> #### 4.5.1 The `a` element
>
> [...]
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used**
>
> Where [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is expected.

Where the context in which an element can be used is where the element is valid and can be used<sup>1</sup>. Phrasing content is defined as such in the specification:

> **Phrasing content** is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing content form [paragraphs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#paragraph).
>
> ```
> a abbr area (if it is a descendant of a map element) audio b bdi bdo br button canvas cite
> code data datalist del dfn em embed i iframe img input ins kbd keygen label map mark 
> math meter noscript object output progress q ruby s samp script select small span strong 
> sub sup svg template textarea time u var video wbr text
> ```

Thus, phrasing content means the text of the document or elements that mark up the text, such as `a` for hyperlinks or `i` for italicization. Any of the above listed elements are applicable. If you look at the [`i` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element):

> #### 4.5.17 The `i` element
>
> [...]
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used**
>
> Where [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is expected.

From the specification, it says that `a` and `i` can be used in the same context, phrasing context. Thus, we can conclude:

- An `a` element inside an `i` element is fine because an `a` element can be used in phrasing content. `i` is phrasing content so it's valid.
- An `i` element inside an `a` element is fine because an `a` element can be used in phrasing content. `a` is phrasing content so it's valid<sup>2</sup>.

With validity aside, which way you choose is totally up to you, one is not more valid than the other.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is usually determined if the element is [block-level or inline](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) but HTML5 has since removed these types in favor for a few more descriptive categories, read more [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories).

<sup>2</sup> Note that even though `a` is phrasing content, you **cannot** have an `a` nested inside another `a`. This is because `a`'s [content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-content-model) does **not** for [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0). Other restrictions might apply for other elements.

Comment: Selected as best answer due to completeness in response.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid.  I'd personally use:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"><i>Google</i></a>
```

because this implies that the text in the `<a>` tag is special.

Comment: Basically what you're saying is that it is a preferential thing?  Which is what I figured.  Thanks!

Comment: @KevinAndrewFogg kind of.  It's more of a context thing than anything.  Again, if it's the text within the link that you want to emphasize, then it should get that tag.  If some links are special and some are not (regardless of text), then you might want to put the `<i>` tag around the `<a>` tag.