# Can I assign a <span> to an <a> element? Syntax?

Tags: html, css, syntax

Is it possible to add a span to an < a > element?  If so what is the appropriate syntax?  These are the two I have tried but neither is working with my CSS.

```
<a span="add_button">+Add a Review</a></span>

<span="add_button"><a>+Add a Review</a></span>
```

Comment: 1) `span` is an invalid custom attribute which won't let you validate your document. 2) `<span="">` span is not an attribute, Element tag in not defined or invalid character `=` with no attribute detected :) In Both cases what you're doing is invalid and I need to suggest you to review some HTML basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `<a href="something"><span>Something</span></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Both `<a>` and `<span>` are [HTML elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element). So, neither of the two you tried is an appropriate syntax.

It seems that you are trying to put a `<span>` inside an `<a>`, or an `<a>` inside a `<span>` ([both of which are perfectly alright, btw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763235/span-inside-anchor-or-anchor-inside-span-or-doesnt-matter)), which would be done as follows:

```
<span id="add_button">
    <a href="some/path">+Add a review</a>
</span>
```

Then, your CSS would look something like:

```
span#add_button {
    /* Rules for the <span> */
}

span#add_button > a {
    /* Rules for the <a> inside the <span> */
}
```